# GenericPool in GLES2(Andengine) - static methods?

Tags: generics, static, sprite, andengine, pool

I'm a beginner at Andengine, but I have read quite a lot of tutorials and such, and I feel that I at least know the basics, but sometimes you run into problems ...

I have done a GenericPool for my sprites. For this I have created a new class. When I'm about to use the pool I have to refer to the GenericPool class from my Main class, of course. But, then the methods in the GenericPool class must be static - which gives me an error - or am I wrong? How should I do this? Almost all of the tutorials I have found is for GLES1, so they are quite hard to follow ...

If you need more information or code, just write!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post the part of the code where you use the GenericPool? To me it seems as if you didn't actually create an instance of the pool and are calling methods on the class itself.

Look here for a nice tutorial on using object pool with AndEngine.
http://wiki.andengine.org/ObjectPool

Also, using object pool may not be necessary. I too was worried about garbage collector stopping the application for tens of milliseconds, but it just doesn't happen to me when using AndEngine.

Comment: Thank you! Yea feels like I miss something ... I've been trying to follow that tutorial, but since it's fot GLES1 it's not that easy to know what to write and not to. I tested writing "SPRITE_POOL = new SpritePool();" - gets error when I write "SPRITE_POOL = new SpritePool(mSpriteTextureRegion);" - but then I must tell that it's about mSpriteTextureRegion somewhere else?

Comment: You need to describe your problem better. What kind of error? SpritePool is not a part of AndEngine, what is inside? Consider not using object pool for the time being, keeping things simple will make it much easier for you to learn how to properly use the many features of AndEngine.

Comment: Ok, I have looked at the tutorial a bit more and now I've got a bit further. Thanks! What I still don't understand is how to finally attach the body and the "face" to the scene. Where should I have the code "scene.attachChild(face);" - in the Pool or in the main? And, should I define a body in the main? Thanks for your time!

Comment: It depends on how you want to create the objects. You can simply do Sprite s = myPool.obtain(); and then connect it with a body and attach it to the scene in main, or you can implement these things in your pool and do the whole batch of things by calling one method, e.g. myPool.obtain(scene, physicsWorld);. Parameters scene and physicsWorld are passed to the method so that it can call the appropriate methods to attach the body and sprite. [continued]

Comment: If you choose this latter approach, you will have to store references to the bodies, sprites and fixtures somewhere, so you may want to create a "middleman" class that will unite them so that you can recycle them easily.